# NullPointerException with PersistenceContext EntityManager in singleton class. How can I solve this?

Tags: java, database, ejb, persistence, entitymanager

Short version: I have a singleton class that should only be initialized once per program execution. The goal of this class is to fetch constant data from the database, which lies in its own table. I've currently got the class set up like this:

```
public class MyService {
    
    private static final MyService INSTANCE =  new MyService(); 
    
    // Evaluates to null
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mydb")
    private EntityManager myEntityManager; 
    
    private int myDbConstant;  
    private MyEnum myEnum;  
    
    public static getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE; 
    }
    
    public int getDbConstant() {
        return myDbConstant;
    }
    
    public MyEnum getMyEnum() {
        return myEnum; 
    }   

   private MyService() {
       readValues();
    }

    // This method fetches the constant values from the database
    private void readValues() {
        List<MyEntity> constantEntities = myEntityManager.createNamedQuery(MyEntity.FIND_ALL).getResultList();  // NullPointerException
        // ...
    }   
}
```

However, this always seems to result in a `NullPointerException` just as the entity manager tries to fetch the entities. I'm not really sure what could be causing this. My project is in an EJB container so my understanding is I'm not supposed to create the EM myself.

Is it possible that the `new MyService();` is the problem? If so, how would I work around it while maintaining the singleton nature of this class?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `MyService` class annotated with appropriate annotations like `@Singletone` or `@Stareless` ?

Comment: It is not currently annotated. Would simply adding an annotation like @Stateless fix it?

Comment: Yes, it would based on the information provided.
Since you want it to be singleton, I suggest adding `@Singleton` annotation and autowire using `@Inject`.

Comment: You mean using @Inject in the class where I want to call the methods of the singleton?

Comment: yes, that is correct.